# Detect Google chrome audio output with applescript

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I am quite new to Applescript and trying to create script to pause Spotify when there is some kind of audio output in Google chrome. Problem is I do not know how to detect if the application is using audio output. There may be some kind of workaround like detecting "This tab is playing audio" in tab hover text. But how to get that text I do not know either.

Comment: have you checked the dictionary ?

Comment: @mcgrailm thanks for the tip, just checked, looks like there is nothing can be done here at this moment. Thanks.